# knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = params$working_dir) - params not found error

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to set my working directory in the Rmarkdown `setup` chunk as follows.

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = params$working_dir)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```
````

My working directory is a parameter in the YAML header.

```
---
title: "Test script"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
params:
  working_dir: "/my/working/directory"
output: html_document
---
```

However, I keep getting the following error.

> Error in resolve(...) : object 'params' not found

Is there a way to get around this?

Full example:

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
params:
  working_dir: "/my/working/dir"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = params$working_dir)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

```{r}
sessionInfo()
```
````

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1 tools_4.2.1    knitr_1.40     xfun_0.33      renv_0.16.0
```

Comment: try moving output to the line before params and see if that has any influence

Comment: This does not fix it unfortunately.

Comment: Please show us a minimal complete document.  I don't get any error when I construct one from the fragments you are showing.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a full example above, but it is essentially the same as what I had before.